# Opening pull down menu problem with Polylang in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I have a problem with the polylang pulldown menu on my website on mobile devices (not on desktops)

I can see a "+" sign next to the language that is active and if I click it, it should open a meny with all the other languages.

But when I click it, it closes the menu instead. If I open that same menu again, I see all my languages there as it should have and the links work as well.

The other "+"/pulldown menus in my menu work fine. It is just the language switcher that does not.

I tried to move the language selector to another place in the menu. This made no difference.
I updated to the latest version.

Any idea on how to fix it?